# data coming in request xml is not storing in SQL .it is showing null value for that field

Tags: knockout.js

i am using xsl for mapping the data but the data coming in request xml is not storing in SQL .it is showing null value for that file.PLZ help me to solve this issue. my code in xsl file is like:

```
l:with-param name="AttributeName" select="'HMDAEthnicityType'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="InterfaceVersion" select="$InterfaceVersion"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="MISMOFieldName" select="'HMDAEthnicityType'"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="GOXGFTLBRRACE"
                mode="BorrowerHMDARace">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@BorrowerRace"
                         mode="BorrowerHMDARace"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <gfsdoc:Mapping MISMOField="HMDARaceType" GFXObject="GOXGFTLBRRACE" GFXProperty="BorrowerRace"/>
  <xsl:template match="GOXGFTLBRRACE/@BorrowerRace" mode="BorrowerHMDARace">
    <xsl:element name="HMDA_RACE"
                 namespace="{$mismoNameSpace}">
      <xsl:call-template name="MakeMISMOAttribute">
        <xsl:with-param name="AttributeName" select="'_Type'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="InterfaceVersion" select="$InterfaceVersion"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="MISMOFieldName"  select="'HMDARaceType'"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="Value"
                        select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

now for this code i am using an virtual machine in which code for same is like: 



    <gfsdoc:Mapping MISMOField="HMDAEthnicityType" GFXObject="GOXGFTLBRADDITIONALDATA" GFXProperty="Ethinicity"/>
      <xsl:template match="GOVERNMENT_MONITORING/@HMDAEthnicityType" mode="GoxGftlbradditionaldata">
        <xsl:call-template name="GetMISMOAttribute">
          <xsl:with-param name="AttributeName" select="'Ethinicity'"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="InterfaceVersion" select="$InterfaceVersion"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="MISMOFieldName" select="'HMDAEthnicityType'"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="HMDA_RACE" mode="GoxGftlbrrace">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
          <xsl:element name="GOXGFTLBRRACE">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="GoxGftlbrrace"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

      <gfsdoc:Mapping MISMOField="HMDA_RACEType" GFXObject="GOXGFTLBRRACE" GFXProperty="BorrowerRace"/>
      <xsl:template match="HMDA_RACE/@_Type" mode="GoxGftlbrrace">
        <xsl:call-template name="GetMISMOAttribute">
          <xsl:with-param name="AttributeName" select="'BorrowerRace'"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="InterfaceVersion" select="$InterfaceVersion"/>
          <!--<xsl:with-param name="MISMOFieldName" select="'HMDARaceType'"/>-->
          <xsl:with-param name="MISMOFieldName" select="'HMDA_RACEType'"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="Value" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:template>
```

..
now my problem is value coming for ethinicity and race in request xml..but same when i checked i DB(SQL) only ethinicity value is storing but not for race

Comment: Your question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: hi,i am using a xsl file in which my code is like